# Sticky Menu issues with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, menu, sticky

I am using the following Java to stick my menu to the top of my page:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $('.nav-container');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 205) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                margin: '0px',
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width()
            });
        } else {
            nav.css({
                position: 'static',
                margin: '115px 0 0 0'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The functionality of the Java works perfectly in every browser except Chrome. In Chrome when you scroll down and back up it creates a 'ghost' menu. You can see it here: [image: The Bespoke Florist with double menu]. You can see the site live here:[The Bespoke Florist](http://www.thebespokeflorist.com). I have replicated this issue on three separate machines but it only seems to be with Chrome. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a chrome issue, I've seen it before. I'm not sure if you can do something about it, but it's certainly not your fault.

Comment: Yea, I figured it was an issue with chrome, however, I see other ways of doing this that work. I just cannot seem to get them to work for me:[link](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/#idc-cover). As far as I can tell the issue is with the way it tests the scroll position. On others it uses the var's top Y and screen position. I just cannot get any of these to work ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question. The issue with Chrome was in hard coding the pixels on the screen. Move to dynamic Div testing and it works without failure. Here is my updated code!

```
    <script>
  jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $('.nav-container'),
        navOff  = nav.offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > navOff.top) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                margin: '0px',
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width()
            });
        } else {
            nav.css({
                position: 'static',
                margin: '115px 0 0 0'
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```